# Bifold Doors for Bedroom

Tags: doors, door-frame

Can anyone advise if I can fit  bifold door in place of a standard bedroom door without changing the door frame?

Comment: Doing so will narrow the opening, of course. And reduce sound isolation. Are you sure you want to do that? If so, it's probably just a matter of ordering the right size and mounting it.

Answer (score 1):

Bifold have a track at the top.  If there's room for that it will work.  You may need to shorten the doors if the top of the door frame is to low.
(I'm guessing you'll not be wanting a bifold with a bottom track as the entrance to a bedroom.)

Doors can easily be shortened by a half inch or so using a circular saw and straight-edge.

Comment: Tha ks for your help. Would I need to remove the door stops?

Comment: no, they are probably still needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this. You'll need to install a track/channel on the header and possibly one on or in the sill, depending on the door you buy, so the door can slide. You might have to remove some excess trim or door stops so the jambs are flat. Depending on the exact size, you might have to get them custome made.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact design of the door frame and the track you may need to modify the frame slightly.

If the *stop* (the strip of wood that a swinging door stops against when it is closed) is much narrower than the bifold door's track, you will either need to position the track in front of or behind the stop, or if that doesn't position the door where you want, to remove the stop.  You can't mount the track on top of a narrow stop that would make it unstable.

Similarly you may want to remove all the stops (along the sides too) in order to maximize the width of the open bifold door, which will be narrower than before.  Removing the stops will also make the door look better. Another option, if there is room along the walls *beside* the door, is to use bifold door hardware that swings the folded open door outside of the opening just like the old swinging regular door.